# WebGL: cannot display two textures

Tags: webgl, textures, skybox

I am trying to render a textured cube (using vertices, indices and tex coords) with a textured skybox (using cubemap) around it but somehow I always get the following error message:

WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets

I have two textures and am probably using gl.activeTexture wrongly but I cannot figure it out.

As you can see, the textured cube breifly flashes before the skybox seems to be drawn over it.

temporary (24h) website with this code: http://priceless-dijkstra-4bf2a5.netlify.com/

Any ideas?

```
<!-- Licensed under a BSD license. See license.html for license -->
<!-- src: https://webglfundamentals.org/ -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <title> WebGL - Textures - Data Texture 3 x2</title>
        <link type = "text/css" href = "./webgl-tutorials.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "description">
            A 3 x2 texture <br />
        </div>
        <canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
    <!-- vertex shader -->
    <script id = "3d-vertex-shader" type = "x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
        uniform mat4 u_matrix;
        varying vec2 v_texcoord;
        void main()
        {
            // Multiply the position by the matrix.
            gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
            // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
            v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- fragment shader -->
    <script id = "3d-fragment-shader" type = "x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        // Passed in from the vertex shader.
        varying vec2 v_texcoord;
        // The texture.
        uniform sampler2D u_texture;
        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
        }
    </script>
    <!--skybox vertex shader-->
    <script id="skybox-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 a_position;
        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() 
        {
          v_position = a_position;
          gl_Position = a_position;
        }
    </script>
    <!--skybox fragment shader-->
    <script id="skybox-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        uniform samplerCube u_skybox;
        uniform mat4 u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse;
        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() 
        {
          vec4 t = u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse * v_position;
          gl_FragColor = textureCube(u_skybox, normalize(t.xyz / t.w));
        }
    </script>
    <script src = "./webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src = "./m4.js"></script>
    <script src = "./primitives.js"></script>
    <script type = "module">
        "use strict";
        function main()
        {
            // Get A WebGL context
            /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
            if (!gl)
            {
                return;
            }
            // setup GLSL program
            var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["3d-vertex-shader", "3d-fragment-shader"]);
            // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
            var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
            var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");
            // lookup uniforms
            var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
            var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

            //create program for skybox
            const skyboxProgramInfo = webglUtils.createProgramInfo(gl, ["skybox-vertex-shader", "skybox-fragment-shader"]);
            var sb_textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(skyboxProgramInfo.program, "u_skybox");
            // create buffers and fill with vertex data
            const cubeBufferInfo = primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
            const quadBufferInfo = primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);
            // Create a texture.
            const sb_texture = gl.createTexture();
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, sb_texture);
            const faceInfos = 
            [
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, url: './pos-x.jpg', },
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, url: './neg-x.jpg', },
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, url: './pos-y.jpg', },
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, url: './neg-y.jpg', },
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, url: './pos-z.jpg', },
                { target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, url: './neg-z.jpg', },
            ];
            faceInfos.forEach((faceInfo) => 
            {
                const {target, url} = faceInfo;
                // Upload the canvas to the cubemap face.
                const level = 0;
                const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
                const width = 512;
                const height = 512;
                const format = gl.RGBA;
                const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
                // setup each face so it's immediately renderable
                gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, null);
                // Asynchronously load an image
                const image = new Image();
                image.src = url;
                image.addEventListener('load', function() 
                {
                    // Now that the image has loaded make copy it to the skybox texture.
                    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
                    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, sb_texture);
                    gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, format, type, image);
                    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
                });
            });
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);


            // Create a buffer for positions
            var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
            // Put the positions in the buffer
            setGeometry(gl);

            // Create a buffer for positions
            var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
            // Put the positions in the buffer
            setIndices(gl);

            // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
            var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
            // Set Texcoords.
            setTexcoords(gl);
            // Create a texture.
            var texture = gl.createTexture();
            //void gl.bindTexture(target, texture);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            // fill texture with 3x2 pixels
            const level = 0;
            const internalFormat = gl.RGB;
            const width = 2;                
            const height = 2;               
            const border = 0;
            const format = gl.RGB;          
            const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
            const data = new Uint8Array     
            ([
                255, 0, 0,      0, 255, 0,
                0, 0, 255,      128, 128, 128,
            ]);
            const alignment = 1;
            gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, alignment);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, format, type, data);
            // set the filtering so we don't need mips and it's not filtered
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            function degToRad(d)
            {
                return d * Math.PI / 180;
            }
            var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);
            var modelXRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
            var modelYRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
            // Get the starting time.
            var then = 0;
            requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
            // Draw the scene.
            function drawScene(time)
            {
                // convert to seconds
                time *= 0.001;
                // Subtract the previous time from the current time
                var deltaTime = time - then;
                // Remember the current time for the next frame.
                then = time;
                webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
                // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
                gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
                gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
                gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
                // Animate the rotation
                modelYRotationRadians += -0.7 * deltaTime;
                modelXRotationRadians += -0.4 * deltaTime;
                // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
                gl.useProgram(program);

                // Turn on the position attribute
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
                // Bind the position buffer.
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
                // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
                var size = 3; // 3 components per iteration
                var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
                var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
                var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
                var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
                gl.vertexAttribPointer( positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

                // Turn on the teccord attribute
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
                // Bind the position buffer.
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
                // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
                var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
                var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
                var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
                var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
                var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
                gl.vertexAttribPointer( texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

                // Compute the projection matrix
                var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
                var projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1, 2000);
                var cameraPosition = [0, 0, 2];
                var up = [0, 1, 0];
                var target = [0, 0, 0];
                // Compute the camera's matrix using look at.
                var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);
                // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
                var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);
                var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
                var matrix = m4.xRotate(viewProjectionMatrix, modelXRotationRadians);
                matrix = m4.yRotate(matrix, modelYRotationRadians);
                // Set the matrix.
                gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
                // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
                gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
                // Draw the geometry.
                gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

                // Skybox: we only care about direction so remove the translation
                var viewDirectionMatrix = m4.copy(viewMatrix);
                viewDirectionMatrix[12] = 0;
                viewDirectionMatrix[13] = 0;
                viewDirectionMatrix[14] = 0;
                var viewDirectionProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewDirectionMatrix);
                var viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix = m4.inverse(viewDirectionProjectionMatrix);
                // draw the skybox
                gl.useProgram(skyboxProgramInfo.program);
                webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, skyboxProgramInfo, quadBufferInfo);
                webglUtils.setUniforms(skyboxProgramInfo, {
                  u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse: viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix,
                  u_skybox: texture,
                });
                // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
                gl.uniform1i(sb_textureLocation, 1);
                webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, quadBufferInfo);

                requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
            }
        }

        // Fill the buffer with the values that define a cube.
        function setGeometry(gl)
        {
            var positions = new Float32Array
            ([  
                // Front face
                -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                 0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                // Back face
                -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                // Top face
                -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
                // Bottom face
                -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                // Right face
                 0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
                 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                 0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                // Left face
                -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,
                -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
                -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,
            ]);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        // Fill the buffer with texture coordinates the cube.
        function setTexcoords(gl)
        {
            gl.bufferData
            (
                gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                new Float32Array
                ([
                    // Front
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                    // Back
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                    // Top
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                    // Bottom
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                    // Right
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                    // Left
                    0.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  0.0,
                    1.0,  1.0,
                    0.0,  1.0,
                ]),
            gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }


        // Fill the buffer with vertex indices
        function setIndices(gl)
        {
            var indices = new Uint16Array
            ([  
                0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
                4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
                8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
                12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
                16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
                20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23,   // left
            ]);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        main();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the code to work I had to do 3 things

1. Bind the indexBuffer before drawing the cube

   ```
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
   ```
2. Don't set the texture at the bottom

   ```
   gl.uniform1i(sb_textureLocation, 1);
   ```
3. Use the correct texture with the skybox

   ```
           webglUtils.setUniforms(skyboxProgramInfo, {
             u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse: viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix,
             u_skybox: texture,      // wrong---------------
             u_skybox: sb_texture,   // right---------------
           });
   ```

A few things.

1. `webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes` sets all the buffers and attributes needed for draw the given object. In this case it means when you call

   ```
         webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, skyboxProgramInfo, quadBufferInfo);
   ```

   the indices needed for the skybox are bound to ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.
   That means the second time through `drawScene` the indexBuffer is not bound
   for your cube.
2. `webglUtils.setUniforms` manages active texture units for you. That means this call

   ```
           webglUtils.setUniforms(skyboxProgramInfo, {
             u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse: viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix,
             u_skybox: texture,
           });
   ```

   was setting `texture` to active unit 0. `setUniforms` just starts at 0 and counts up for each texture used. `texture` the wrong texture for `u_skybox` which is why you got the error. the code above translates to

   ```
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_viewDirectionProjectionInverseLocation, false, viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
    gl.uniform1i(u_skyboxLocation, 0);
   ```

Texture units are generally something you only care about at draw time, not init time. They are an array of **global** places to attach textures for the next draw call. Between every draw call you're expected to set them up however is needed for the draw all you're about to make.

```
For each texture the shaders used by the next draw call need
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + n);
    gl.bindTexture(targetTypeForTexture, texture);
    gl.uniform1i(n);
```

Also see https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-texture-units.html

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }
  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["3d-vertex-shader", "3d-fragment-shader"]);
  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");
  // lookup uniforms
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
  var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

  //create program for skybox
  const skyboxProgramInfo = webglUtils.createProgramInfo(gl, ["skybox-vertex-shader", "skybox-fragment-shader"]);
  var sb_textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(skyboxProgramInfo.program, "u_skybox");
  // create buffers and fill with vertex data
  const cubeBufferInfo = primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);
  const quadBufferInfo = primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);
  // Create a texture.
  const sb_texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, sb_texture);
  const faceInfos = [
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/pos-x.jpg',
    },
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/neg-x.jpg',
    },
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/pos-y.jpg',
    },
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/neg-y.jpg',
    },
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/pos-z.jpg',
    },
    {
      target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
      url: 'https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/images/computer-history-museum/neg-z.jpg',
    },
  ];
  faceInfos.forEach((faceInfo) => {
    const {
      target,
      url
    } = faceInfo;
    // Upload the canvas to the cubemap face.
    const level = 0;
    const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
    const width = 512;
    const height = 512;
    const format = gl.RGBA;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    // setup each face so it's immediately renderable
    gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, null);
    // Asynchronously load an image
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Now that the image has loaded make copy it to the skybox texture.
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, sb_texture);
      gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, format, type, image);
      gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    });
  });
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);


  // Create a buffer for positions
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put the positions in the buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  // Create a buffer for positions
  var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  // Put the positions in the buffer
  setIndices(gl);

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  // Set Texcoords.
  setTexcoords(gl);
  // Create a texture.
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  //void gl.bindTexture(target, texture);
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  // fill texture with 3x2 pixels
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGB;
  const width = 2;
  const height = 2;
  const border = 0;
  const format = gl.RGB;
  const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const data = new Uint8Array([
    255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
    0, 0, 255, 128, 128, 128,
  ]);
  const alignment = 1;
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, alignment);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, format, type, data);
  // set the filtering so we don't need mips and it's not filtered
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }
  var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);
  var modelXRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
  var modelYRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
  // Get the starting time.
  var then = 0;
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene(time) {
    // convert to seconds
    time *= 0.001;
    // Subtract the previous time from the current time
    var deltaTime = time - then;
    // Remember the current time for the next frame.
    then = time;
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    // Animate the rotation
    modelYRotationRadians += -0.7 * deltaTime;
    modelXRotationRadians += -0.4 * deltaTime;
    // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3; // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Turn on the teccord attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

    // Compute the projection matrix
    var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    var projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1, 2000);
    var cameraPosition = [0, 0, 2];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var target = [0, 0, 0];
    // Compute the camera's matrix using look at.
    var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);
    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);
    var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
    var matrix = m4.xRotate(viewProjectionMatrix, modelXRotationRadians);
    matrix = m4.yRotate(matrix, modelYRotationRadians);
    // Set the matrix.
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);
    // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
    // Draw the geometry.
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Skybox: we only care about direction so remove the translation
    var viewDirectionMatrix = m4.copy(viewMatrix);
    viewDirectionMatrix[12] = 0;
    viewDirectionMatrix[13] = 0;
    viewDirectionMatrix[14] = 0;
    var viewDirectionProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewDirectionMatrix);
    var viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix = m4.inverse(viewDirectionProjectionMatrix);
    // draw the skybox
    gl.useProgram(skyboxProgramInfo.program);
    webglUtils.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, skyboxProgramInfo, quadBufferInfo);
    webglUtils.setUniforms(skyboxProgramInfo, {
      u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse: viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix,
      u_skybox: sb_texture,
    });
    // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
    webglUtils.drawBufferInfo(gl, quadBufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a cube.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  var positions = new Float32Array([
    // Front face
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
    // Back face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    // Top face
    -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
    // Bottom face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
    // Right face
    0.5, -0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.5,
    // Left face
    -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
  ]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Fill the buffer with texture coordinates the cube.
function setTexcoords(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
      // Front
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      // Back
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      // Top
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      // Bottom
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      // Right
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      // Left
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}


// Fill the buffer with vertex indices
function setIndices(gl) {
  var indices = new Uint16Array([
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // front
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // back
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // top
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // bottom
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // right
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23, // left
  ]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<div class = "description">
    A 3 x2 texture <br />
</div>
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>

    <!-- vertex shader -->
    <script id = "3d-vertex-shader" type = "x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
        uniform mat4 u_matrix;
        varying vec2 v_texcoord;
        void main()
        {
            // Multiply the position by the matrix.
            gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
            // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
            v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        }
    </script>
    <!-- fragment shader -->
    <script id = "3d-fragment-shader" type = "x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        // Passed in from the vertex shader.
        varying vec2 v_texcoord;
        // The texture.
        uniform sampler2D u_texture;
        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
        }
    </script>
    <!--skybox vertex shader-->
    <script id="skybox-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 a_position;
        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() 
        {
          v_position = a_position;
          gl_Position = a_position;
        }
    </script>
    <!--skybox fragment shader-->
    <script id="skybox-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        uniform samplerCube u_skybox;
        uniform mat4 u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse;
        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() 
        {
          vec4 t = u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse * v_position;
          gl_FragColor = textureCube(u_skybox, normalize(t.xyz / t.w));
        }
    </script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/primitives.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much!
I find WebGLutils complicates things for me.
I am so trying to make it all work with only webgl calls but all tutorials seem to package things up in endless functions calling functions calling functions.
Somehow pure Webgl actually seems simpler, at least for a guy who once did OpenGL in C

Comment: You probably started in the middle instead of the beginning? At some point all the WebGL code gets to be too much. The first 15 or 20 aritcles use nothing but raw WebG but at some point you should know the material. You should know there are only 5 or 6 things you need to do. Compile shaders, look up locations, setup attributes and buffers, set uniforms, bind textures. At that point cluttering the examples with 150 lines of WebGL loses the point. The point is how to use the basics to achieve your result, not about individual WebGL functions.